# write PHP inside HTML inside PHP

Tags: php, html

in trying to put in php code inside html that inside php,
my goal is to full this select option with an array

```
       <?php 
        $wcr=array(
             'Angola',
             'Antigua & Barbuda',
             'Armenia', 
             'Austria',
             'Azerbaijan', 
          );

          $content = '<div class="row">
                <form role="form">
                  
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputName1">Name</label>
                                <select name="country"><option selected value="">' 
                                <? $p=1;asort($wcr);reset($wcr);
                                while (list ($p, $val) = each ($wcr)) {
                                echo '<option value="'.$p.'">'.$val;
                                } ?>
                                '</select>
                    </div>

                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="AddDoctor()" 
                    value="Submit"></input>
                </form>
          </div>';
        ?>
```

i tried a different approach but nothing seems to work

Comment: you can put PHP inside HTML by using `?>` to get out of PHP mode. But you can't put it inside quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP isn't inside the HTML. You ended the quoted string, so you're still in PHP execution mode, you don't need `<?php` again.

The loop shouldn't use `echo`, it should append to the `$content` string.

Also, `each()` has been deprecated, you should use a `foreach` loop.

```
<?php 
$wcr=array(
    'Angola',
    'Antigua & Barbuda',
    'Armenia', 
    'Austria',
    'Azerbaijan', 
    );

$content = '<div class="row">
                <form role="form">
                  
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputName1">Name</label>
                                <select name="country"><option selected value="">';
 
asort($wcr);
foreach ($wcr as $p => $val) {
    $content .= '<option value="'.$p.'">'.$val.'</option>';
}
$content .= '</select>
        </div>

        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="AddDoctor()" 
                value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
</div>';
?>
```